# sudo & ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: docker

System ubuntu 20.04. I have reinstalled docker at least twice. And I run docker-compose with sudo, always.

```
 $ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-07-21 09:18:05 EDT; 8min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket

$ ps |grep docker
root      263393  0.0  0.4 1614204 74504 ?       Ssl  09:18   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

$ sudo docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it different without the sudo in the docker-compose up command ? If your user is in the docker group (is it ?) you shouldn't need the sudo.

Comment: Paul, same error without sudo. I have been using docker for years now, and always used sudo, without a docker group. I just added myself to the docker group and same error.

Comment: using `sudo` for docker is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work either way.

Comment: Some people have the same problem here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181 a lot of solutions are suggested, maybe one can help you ?

Comment: Paul, I read through that and nothing worked for me. I have not tried manually adding docker with curl.  I'd like to have automated updates. But that might be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Well after uninstalling / reinstalling docker 3 or 4 times, I thought I would do a full apt update and upgrade. I thought that was being done automatically, but there was some kind of error in apt which had to be fixed manually. After that, I noticed some docker related services were being upgraded! Then after that everything went back to normal and docker was working like it should. Sheesh.